# why cant i initialize 3 default parameters at a time in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012

```
class Complex 
{
private:

float rp, ip;
//const int a=10;
//static int b;
//static const int c = 50;
public:
Complex();
//Complex(float );
/*Complex(float,float);*/
Complex(float , float = 20, float = 30);
}
```

The above code works fine but when i try to have 3 default parameters

```
class Complex
{
private:
float rp, ip;
//const int a=10;//static int b;//static const int c = 50;
public:
Complex();
//Complex(float );
/*Complex(float,float);*/
Complex(float =10  , float = 20, float = 30);
}
```

I get the below error -

> main.cpp(12): error C2668: 'Complex::Complex' : ambiguous call to
>   overloaded function
>       complex.h(15): could be 'Complex::Complex(float,float,float)'
>       complex.h(12): or       'Complex::Complex(void)'

Comment: Did you read the error message, or just assume it was incomprehensible?

Comment: The error message seems perfectly clear. When you call a constructor with no parameters, the compiler can't decide which of the two you mean.

Comment: how does that relate to the first parameter inittialization.can u please elaborate..
@Benjamin : when i try to initiliaze the first parameter, why doesnt it compile.And iam not able to get the answer from this error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because the compiler cannot know which of the two different functions you mean when you write

```
Complex c;
```

Does that call

```
Complex();
```

or

```
Complex(float,float,float);
```

with the three default values?

You can get around this by removing the `Complex()` constructor and have default construction be handled by the `Complex(float,float,float)` constructor with the three default values.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor with three default args conflicts with your no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is ambigious. The compiler is unable to understand constructor you want to call if you construct `Complex` with no arguments: whether it is the default constructor

```
Complex();
```

or the constructor with three arguments all defaulted:

```
Complex(float =10  , float = 20, float = 30);
```

Both of these constructors would match if you do

```
Complex c;
```

or

```
new Complex();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message lays it out pretty clearly.

The problem is that because all 3 arguments are defaulted, the compiler has no idea how to deduce what function overload you're talking about.

```
// default constructor, or 3 defaulted floats?
Complex a;
```